# How to render a view as a entity field on form edit?

Tags: views, entities, commerce

I'm looking for a module (or alternative solution) to render view in the field.

Similar to [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield), but it should be rendered when filling the form ([Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) or node edit).

The purpose for that is to include Commerce views in the entity form (such as commerce_cart_form, commerce_cart_summary, commerce_payment_order) which are actually views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva)  module. It will provide the view as field. So in display settings you can assign views the region you would like. Quite simple and useful module

Comment: Assalam-o-alaykum Can you answer this? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238447/attach-or-embed-node-add-form-to-a-view